dataframe filter groupby based on a subset
df_example = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                          'class': [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2],
                          'price': [3, 4, 2, 1, 6, 5]})

I want to filter each name where the price is larger than the smallest price in a subset class==2 within name grounp:
df_example.sort_values(['name', 'price'], inplace=True)
df_tem = df_example[df_example['class'] == 2].groupby('name').first()

Below is the pseudocode:
df_example.groupby('name').apply(lambda key, val: val['price'] > df_tem.loc[key]['price']).reset_index()

Is there any effective way to achieve something like filter dataframe based on a subset within groupby
result:
the smallest price with class=2 for each name group df_tem:
    class   price
name        
a   2   2
b   2   5

Therefore,
group a: price>2; group b: price>5

the output:
pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'a', 'b'],
                          'class': [1, 2, 2],
                          'price': [3, 4, 6]})

Update:
actually i have an idea that create a new column called smallest, then filter
df_example by df_example['price'] > df_example['smallest ']. 

Do you know how to quickly create such column something like
df_example['smallest '] = df_example[df_example['class'] == 2].groupby('name')['price'].transform('first')

above way still have nan

@Ben.T pls see the update, the expected filtered dataframe

Code
Use groupby to aggregate the minimum and use map to map the result to name column for boolean indexing.
m = df_example[df_example['class'] == 2].groupby('name')['price'].min()
out = df_example[df_example['price'] > df_example['name'].map(m)]

out
  name  class  price
0    a      1      3
1    a      2      4
4    b      2      6


update additional question
Additionally, if you want to include name for which class=2 does not exist, use the code below
m = df_example[df_example['class'] == 2].groupby('name')['price'].min()
cond1 = df_example['price'] > df_example['name'].map(m)
cond2 = ~df_example['name'].isin(m.index)
out = df_example[cond1 | cond2]

new example
df_example = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
                          'class': [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3],
                          'price': [3, 4, 2, 1, 6, 5, 5]})

out:
  name  class  price
0    a      1      3
1    a      2      4
4    b      2      6
6    c      3      5


very good answer, but I may forget a case, when the name is not in map, say name = 'c', class=3, price=5, I still want to keep those rows.

@user6703592 i update my answer

You can do it using groupby.transform to align the min value per name where class==2 and compare gt (greater than) with the price of the row
df_output = (
    df_example
    .loc[lambda x: 
         x['price'].gt(x['price'].where(x['class'].eq(2))
                       .groupby(x['name']).transform(min))]
)
print(df_output)
#   name  class  price
# 0    a      1      3
# 1    a      2      4
# 4    b      2      6


actually i have an idea that create a new column called smallest, then filter df_example by df_example['price'] > df_example['smallest ']. Do you know how to quickly create such column something like df_example['smallest '] = df_example[df_example['class'] == 2].groupby('name')['price'].transform('first'), above way still have nan value

@user6703592 yes you can do df_example['smallest'] = df_example['price'].where(df_example['class'].eq(2)).groupby(df_example['name']).transform(min) but I don't see the point to create the column if you don't use this value other than for filtering

You can get the min price for class 2, merge it into df_example as a new column min_price, then use that to filter:
m = (
    df_example[df_example["class"] == 2]
    .groupby("name")["price"]
    .min()
    .reset_index(name="min_price")
)

df_example = (
    df_example.merge(m, how="left", on="name")
    .query("price > min_price")
    .drop(columns="min_price")
)

  name  class  price
0    a      1      3
1    a      2      4
4    b      2      6


sorry, incorrectly edit on your answer
